# Is it possible to bind a custom function instead of an event to a div in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if this is possible, I was able to do this with AS3. Is it possible to bind a listener on div that only listens for mouse events. So lets say I have a div called "lion", typically this is how a mouse event is bind:

```
  $("#mouse").bind("click", function(e)
  {
     alert(e.currentTarget.id);
  }
```

But as you can see, the mouse event has already been declared as "click". What I would like to do is write a function and then bind that function to "lion" the div. And when lion encounters such mouse events then function is able to capture the mouse event type. Here is the function:

```
  $.fn.chkType = function(e)
  {
    var evt = e.type;
    var str = "";

    switch(evt)
    {
      case "mouseover":
      str = "MOUSE OVER";
      break;

      case "mouseout":
      str = "MOUSE OUT";
      break;

      case "click":
      str = "CLICK";
      break;

      default:
      break;
   }

   alert(str);
  }
```

And now if I would like to assign this function to "lion", I am not certain how would this be possible? I have done a lot search and the closest I came was at:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

I would appreciate your input. 
Thank you.

Comment: You can attach functions, as 'event handlers' to a DOM element's events (click, mouseover, mouseout etc). Attaching a function to the element itself doesn't make sense. This applies whether you are using jQuery or plain old javascript (POJS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest binding to all of the events that you want to bind to.

```
$("#mouse").bind("click mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
    //alert(e.currentTarget.id);
    //alert(e.type);
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

**Update**
What was the purpose of the `$.chkType` method? why not just alert the type directly?

Comment: You use spaces, not commas to separate events in `bind`.

Comment: `alert(str);` ====> `return str;`?

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. I realize there has to be a event trigger somewhere. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own custom events, and bind them to elements.  You can even bind the same function to multiple events.  (P.S. In jQuery 1.7+, use `on` instead of `bind`)

```
$("#mouse").on("lion click", function(e){
    alert(e.type);
});
```

Now `#mouse` has a `lion` event attached to it.  Obviously, the browser cannot trigger this event, but you can.

```
$("#mouse").trigger('lion');​
```

This will trigger your custom `lion` event.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bav4K/2/

NOTE: `$.fn` is used to attach functions to jQuery objects.  In your case that doesn't make much sense (you're not gonna call `$('#mouse').chkType()`), I'd suggest using `$.chkType` instead.

Comment: I would suggest cluttering neither the jQuery namespace or the jQuery.fn namespace unless there is good reason.

Comment: Thank you, Rocket for your help. Appreciate it.